# Understanding memory map while loading firmware to IDA

Tags: embedded, reverse-engineering, ida

I have a binary which is a bootloader of the proccessor named V850ES/FJ3. This is the manual I have - [R01UH0237ED0320 Rev. 3.20](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/doc/products/mpumcu/doc/v850/R01UH0237ED0320_V850ESFx3.pdf?key=4ed980f4dcb18937b7e7e66caa2b3968).

According to what I read in the PDF, I put these values in the memory:

[image]

I pressed C and set up the initialization point. Now, these are the functions that I got:

[image: IDA Functions]

My question is, when I see this:
[image: Some instructions]

I can set more functions with "C", so eventually, I will end up with all of the functions. So, how do you know where to set a beginning of a function? Are all the functions in the code are only the 4 ones that I showed in the screenshot? If not - how do you find more?

Comment: Surely the amount of physical memory is irrelevant - the application need not even use all of it.  I am not sure you even need to distinguish between ROM and RAM - if the code modifies it it is clearly not ROM.  What you do need to know is the start address of the code.  Everything in your binary image will be loaded somewhere into the ROM area by definition.  Whether it is loaded at address 0 may depend on whether it runs from reset or if there is a bootloader that runs first.

Comment: The lack of addresses in the memory map is because it is part specific and that diagram is from the generic V850E1 core manual.  Figure 3-4 in https://docs.rs-online.com/1b35/0900766b8144b509.pdf has specific addresses for these regions for specific parts.  However I still suggest that it is irrelevant top your disassembly attempt.

Comment: Hi @Clifford, first - thanks for answering. The binary is the bootloader of the proccessor named V850ES/FJ3. This is the manual I've got -https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/doc/products/mpumcu/doc/v850/R01UH0237ED0320_V850ESFx3.pdf?key=4ed980f4dcb18937b7e7e66caa2b3968. I really don't understand what to put in each of these - https://ibb.co/wWvLVdf . It seems wrong every time I try

Comment: I did not answer, I commented. The kind of detailed information you posted in your comment should be in the question - edit it to add. However "it seems wrong" us far too vague. You need to describe the result you got, and the result you expected, and exactly what it is that seems wrong to you.  We can (or should) only answer from information in the question, not comments.  SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Your memory map is clearly incorrect.  It is not possible to tell you the correct settings because there are five FJ3 variants - you need to specify the _exact_ part number.  See figures 7.1 and 7.2.  You also seem to be confusing _size_ with _end address_ - a memory with address range 0x000 to 0x3ff, has size 0x400.  Not all the program area is available to all parts, and not all of it is Code Flash.  It seems to me you are ill-equipped to do this reverse-engineering, and are expecting the tool to provide expertise that you need to posses _a priori_.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed those and still there's a question of how to distinguish between each function correctly. I know I'm a beginner in this but still this is something that I want to do and every little progress I make gains me more knowledge about this topic

Comment: If it is simple enough, it is plausible that the are are only 4 subroutine in the bootloader - I am not familiar with either the code, the part of even IDA.  You might inspect the interrupt vector table for interrupt and exception handler addresses - the tool might not process those automatically I guess?  Beyond that I imagine it follows the thread of execution from a single "from reset" entry point.

Comment: If the code is multi-threaded, or invokes functions through pointers it may miss other entry points and functions.  The code may even include "dead code" that is never called - reversing that serves little purpose.

Comment: You might sum the length of all the routines you have found and compare that with the sizeof the image itself.  Of course some of it may be constant data and initialisers, but a bootloader might have little need for large amounts of that.  I would also question the benefit of reversing this code; what do you hope to achieve by it?